# Implement "windows explorer"-like component in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-2013, directory

I am looking for a way to implement a component in .net that would allow users to see a list of files within a specific folder, but to also be able to sort those files by date, name, size, etc.. Basically, implement the "windows explorer" functions in a form.

Currently, I am using a listbox. This component has no column headings or even columns for that matter.

in case it isn't clear, this is from "my computer", pretty standard. This is what I would like to implement. Does anyone know of a library or a component that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: the listview is probably what you want

Comment: @DrewJordan yes that is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by DrewJordan, DataGridView was what I was looking for as it implements sorting on columns by default.

Answer (score 0):

VB has some great built in functionality to make this easy.  Start here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32kbeb6.aspx

If I were doing this, I think I'd build my own.  But, if you want something out-o-the-box, this might work.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Telerik makes powerful plugins, but they are not always easy to use.

Comment: That's quite broad, and I am already using some techniques in there. I am looking specifically for a control that will allow me to sort files found in a directory, not how to find files in a directory.

Comment: Yeah my answer was broad.  The thing is, what you are looking to do can be accomplished in a very few lines of code.  Off the top of my head I don't know any out-of-the-box third party plugins that do this.  I can google as well as you can, but in all honesty, for the time it takes you to find one and implement it, you could build your own.

Comment: :-) First, I updated my answer.  Second, write them yourself!  This form isn't to get people to write code for you.  It's to have people offer specific help when you are having trouble writing your own.  The link I provided to the msdn page will have sample code for you.

Comment: Here's a better link that will give you actual FileSystem commands to read folders on files on your hard drive.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.aspx

Comment: While I greatly appreciate your help, I think you may need to re-read the question. I am not looking for functions to help me read folder contents, I am looking specifically for a control that implements either exactly, or something like the windows explorer set of tools to allow sorting and selection. I am already using exactly what you have suggested, and am looking for a better solution. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Understood.  And my point is:  If your needs are specific, and you are not finding what you want, then write it yourself.  Heck, once it's coded, you could package it and sell it!

Comment: Haha, I'd love to but unfortunately my employer wouldnt appreciate me spending time writing software if it already exists. So I suppose the short answer to my question is no?

Comment: If the Telerik control isn't doing it for you, I'm out of idea.  I assume you have spent time looking, and have come up with nothing.  Have you been told by your employer to find a control?  I'm curious what you have against coding this yourself. In the time we've been trading comments, you could be 25% done.